# Groovy: method cannot be applied to (capture<?>)

Tags: groovy, typechecking

I'm playing with Groovy's static typechecker and ran into an interesting issue. I've got a Groovy method calling a Java method. On the Groovy side, I've got

```
import com.restfb.Parameter
import com.restfb.Connection
import com.restfb.Version
import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient

@TypeChecked
static List<Map<String, String>> getPages(accessToken, query) {
    Connection<Page> conn = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.VERSION_2_5).fetchConnection(
            "search", Page.class,
            Parameter.with("q", query),
            Parameter.with("type", "page"),
            Parameter.with("fields", "name,about"),
            Parameter.with("limit", 100)
    );

    conn.data.flatten().collect { p -> page2map(p) } // error here
}
```

On the Java side, I've got

```
public static Map<String, String> page2map(Page page) {
    Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
    res.put("likes", page.getName());
    // some more stuff here
    return res;
}
```

Without typechecking, this code runs fine. With typechecking, I get `method cannot be applied to (capture<?>)` compiler error at the last line of the Groovy code. I'm running Groovy 2.4.6. Any suggestions?

Comment: try define `p`'s type explicitelty: `.collect { Page p -> ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Groovy defaults and assumes that you are being extremely generic. This has caught me off-guard when trying to talk to Java.

I suspect that `flatten` or `collect` is giving you an `ArrayList` or `HashMap`. That inline closure may be returning `Object`.

Since you are not specifying what `collect` is returning explicitly, I'm going to expect that it will be returning an `ArrayList<Object>`, and the inline-closure will be of the signature `Object f(Object x)`.

Try being extremely explicit with (roughly) the following

```
Map<String, String> my_method(Page p) = { return page2map(p) }
List<Map<String, String>> container;
container = conn.data.flatten().collect(my_method)
return container
```

I would also look at the generated groovy stubs for more insight as to what's going on to see exactly what types are being tossed around. The closure you are using will appear something along the lines of `TheClass$getPages$Inline$Closure$1`

You could also consider against using `@TypeChecked`, as not having to deal with types is an advantage of using Groovy in the first place.

Also, you may mean `ClassName.page2map` rather than `page2map`